# How to write derivatives in Maxima

Tags: derivatives, maxima-software

I need to write in Maxima the following expression, where $f$ is a generic function of $x$ not specified:

$$
f'(e) - 1 \quad \text{or} \quad \left.\dfrac{df}{dx}\right|_{x=e}-1
$$

I'm trying to making it differentiating a general $f(x)$ and then applying the substitution of $x$ by $e$, but I'm getting the wrong result:

[image]

Does anybody know how to get the correct expression of that generic derivative evaluated at $e$?

Comment: `at(diff(f(x),x),x=%e)`